# Character separator between horizontal list items with control over space on each side of the separator

Tags: css, list

Using `:before` and `content: " - "` I can easily place a `-` character between each of my horizontal list items.

But then I have zero control over the space between the items and the separator. Apparently one single space is the only option and I want much more space than that.

Any idea how to control this?

Comment: use margin to add more space.  Such as li:before { content: " - "; margin-right: 15px; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could just use left/right padding on your :before element instead of a space.